# Python Socket Data looks like unicode but cannot be translated

Tags: python, unicode

I'm new to Python CGI , wanted to translate a Minecraft MOTD Script from my php project,which is using a Socket to get the data from the Server

Here's my source code:

```
 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = "example.com"
    port = 25565
    s.connect((host, port))
    s.sendall(b"\xFE\x01", 0)
    msg = s.recv(4096)
    s.close
    print(msg)
```

It can connect to the server and send back the MOTD data,but it looks weird

```
b'\xff\x00>\x00\xa7\x001\x00\x00\x001\x002\x007\x00\x00\x00B\x00u\x00n\x00g\x00e\x00e\x00C\x00o\x00r\x00d\x00 \x001\x00.\x008\x00.\x00x\x00-\x001\x00.\x001\x002\x00.\x00x\x00\x00\x00\xa7\x00f\x00\xa7\x001\x00A\x00n\x00o\x00t\x00h\x00e\x00r\x00 \x00B\x00u\x00n\x00g\x00e\x00e\x00 \x00s\x00e\x00r\x00v\x00e\x00r\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x002\x000\x000' --> -->
```

I've tried to find what it is , it looks like UTF-16
and i've tried this to solve the problem:

```
msg.decode('UTF-16')
```

but sadly , it didnt work

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x30 in position 126: truncated data 
      args = ('utf-16-le', b'\xff\x00>\x00\xa7\x001\x00\x00\x001\x002\x007\...0v\x00e\x00r\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x002\x000\x000', 126, 127, 'truncated data') 
      encoding = 'utf-16-le' 
      end = 127 
      object = b'\xff\x00>\x00\xa7\x001\x00\x00\x001\x002\x007\...0v\x00e\x00r\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x002\x000\x000' 
      reason = 'truncated data' 
      start = 126 
      with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of UnicodeDecodeError object>
```

Python couldnt translate these code to text , which confused me a lot.
I'm new in programming , is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: How did you decode the response in Php?

Comment: @Bernhard in PHP , i used UTF-16BE to decode $Data = SubStr( $Data, 3 );  $Data = iconv( 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8', $Data );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping#1.6, the first three bytes are a packet ID and size of the following UTF-16BE string:

> **Server to client**
>
> The server responds with a 0xFF kick packet. The packet begins with a single byte identifier ff, then a two-byte
>   big endian short giving the length of the following string in
>   characters. You can actually ignore the length because the server
>   closes the connection after the response is sent.
>
> After the first 3 bytes, the packet is a UTF-16BE string. It begins
>   with two characters: §1, followed by a null character. On the wire
>   these look like `00 a7 00 31 00 00`.
>
> The remainder is null character (that is 00 00) delimited fields:
>
> 1. Protocol version (e.g. 74)
> 2. Minecraft server version (e.g. 1.8.7)
> 3. Message of the day (e.g. A Minecraft Server)
> 4. Current player count
> 5. Max players

So strip the first three bytes, then decode:

```
>>> data = b'\xff\x00>\x00\xa7\x001\x00\x00\x001\x002\x007\x00\x00\x00B\x00u\x00n\x00g\x00e\x00e\x00C\x00o\x00r\x00d\x00 \x001\x00.\x008\x00.\x00x\x00-\x001\x00.\x001\x002\x00.\x00x\x00\x00\x00\xa7\x00f\x00\xa7\x001\x00A\x00n\x00o\x00t\x00h\x00e\x00r\x00 \x00B\x00u\x00n\x00g\x00e\x00e\x00 \x00s\x00e\x00r\x00v\x00e\x00r\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x002\x000\x000'
>>> data[3:].decode('utf-16be').split('\x00')
['§1', '127', 'BungeeCord 1.8.x-1.12.x', '§f§1Another Bungee server', '6', '200']
```

Comment: theres still a problem here , Minecraft MOTD started to use JSON after Minecraft 1.7 , which causes Socket solution could only get the `old motd` from the server. thanks for your explainations :D

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a `truncated data` because your data is, indeed, truncated. It has a length of 127 bytes, decoding it from UTF-16 requires either 126 or 128 bytes of data (an even number of bytes, that is).

Removing the trailing `\x00` bytes and decoding gives the following:

```
>>> a = b'\xff\x00>\x00\xa7\x001\x00\x00\x001\x002\x007\x00\x00\x00B\x00u\x00n\x00g\x00e\x00e\x00C\x00o\x00r\x00d\x00 \x001\x00.\x008\x00.\x00x\x00-\x001\x00.\x001\x002\x00.\x00x\x00\x00\x00\xa7\x00f\x00\xa7\x001\x00A\x00n\x00o\x00t\x00h\x00e\x00r\x00 \x00B\x00u\x00n\x00g\x00e\x00e\x00 \x00s\x00e\x00r\x00v\x00e\x00r\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x002\x00'
>>> a.decode("utf-16")
u'\xff>\xa71\x00127\x00BungeeCord 1.8.x-1.12.x\x00\xa7f\xa71Another Bungee server\x006\x002'
>>>
```

Comment: after i've tried to remove the trail by `r = a[:-3]` it could help me to fix the error , but when i tried to `print(r)` it just output a `body background` to my browser . when it is running on Python , not CGI everything is fine

Comment: I'm not really know how Python print out data to the browser. so how is it happend

Comment: Mmh I'm not really sure what setup you're using. What are you using to run python online? The string is a unicode string, so maybe you have to use a unicode-specific method to remove the last 3 bytes

Comment: Apache 2.4.9 + Python 3.x running on Windows 10 , webpage is using utf-8 format

Comment: ok , i found a solution to fix it `result = removedmsg.decode('utf-16')`  `print(result.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: Be sure to check Mark's answer, I provided you a rough solution without knowledge of the actual encoding, you'll get a much cleaner data with his solution.

Comment: still thanks, at least i know its about byte from you, thanks for helping :D